# avr-gcc array with pointers to functions in program (flash) memory

Tags: avr, avr-gcc

How can I move an array with pointers to functions into flash? In normal RAM, the code looks something like:

MCU = ATMega628P, 
AVR-GCC 4.3.3 (WinAVR 20100110)

```
typedef void (*func_ptr_t)(void);

const func_ptr_t cli_func_list[] = {
        &funcA,
        &funcB
};

...
(*cli_func_list[j])(); // execute
...
```

I did try something like

```
const func_ptr_t cli_func_list[] PROGMEM = {
        &cmd_OT,
        &cmd_TT
};
```

but have no clue how to make this work. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please explain why you try to do that and what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Got an answer at the avrfreaks forum. [here](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=138706)

Comment: @Lemoi link broken

Answer (score 0):

You got is almost right, but you have to use `pgm_read_xxx` from `avr/pgmspace.h` to read from flash. This applies to C++ and to avr-gcc older than v4.7:

```cpp
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>

typedef void (*func_t)(void);

void funcA (void) {}
void funcB (void) {}

const func_t funcs[] PROGMEM =
{
    &funcA,
    &funcB
};

void call_func (int i)
{
    func_t fun = (func_t) pgm_read_word (&funcs[i]);
    fun();
}
```

With avr-gcc v4.7+, you can use the `__flash` qualifier, are type-save and no need for `avr/pgmspace.h`:

```cpp
// With avr-gcc v4.7+
const __flash func_t funcs2[] =
{
    &funcA,
    &funcB
};

void call_func2 (int i)
{
    funcs2[i] ();
}
```